# Is Marlin capable to work with binary G-code?

Tags: marlin, g-code, repetier

I want to use a binary protocol like Repetier uses.

Can Marlin work with this/such a protocol?

Answer (score 3):

No. Marlin only supports ASCII G-code, and does not (currently) support binary format. According to the [List of Firmware](http://reprap.org/wiki/List_of_Firmware), Repetier is the only firmware that supports binary G-code. Moreover, verifying with Marlin's source code, shows that the [G-code parser](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/gcode.cpp) can only handle traditional G-code.